# Macbook optical drive constantly checks for media after boot/wake from sleep and won't accept discs

Tags: mac, macbook, osx-leopard, optical-drive

The slot-loading optical drive on a Macbook (2006) running won't accept a disc when inserted--unless it is partially inserted and then slept/waken or the "Disc Burning" section of System Profiler is visited.

Also, when booted or awakened from sleep, the optical drive **constantly/repeatedly** checks for media for around 20 seconds or so. I know it's normal for every Mac to check for media **once** at these times so the system knows if there's a disc inserted or not, and I know it makes a sound, but this is unusually long.

The Macbook passes the self-hardware test (even the extended one you get to by pressing D at boot) and the optical drive will play back the media fine once loaded.

The Macbook's software is up to date.

Any ideas besides a PRAM reset?